# How to populate picklist values in Lightning Componets according to the metadata definition?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, picklist, inputfield, selectoption

In Visualforce, we didn't thought much about picklist-values (=options) on simple CRUD UIs - they where simply there using an `<apex:inputField ... />`

Now in Lightning I found this documentation showing different verbose ways to populate the options either by Markup or JavaScript, but both none driven by metadata - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ui_select.htm

I like neither of those approaches. Is there any method to get this done better?

The goal is, to populate the values as defined in the setup

- Record-Type aware
- Translation aware
- Dependency aware

A similar (but more specific) question has been asked here [Picklist Values in Dynamic Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79235/picklist-values-in-dynamic-lightning-components)

I think in addition to record-type specific values, there are many reasons to make this dynamic, e. g. translations. It is not simple to populate a picklist with exactly the same values as user will see in the standard-UI. Assuming an complex org is already well-configured, it might be a huge piece of work to populate the picklists (reading the schema, evaluating the record-types, translations, etc). This should be done - as in Visualforce - by the platform, but how does it work?

To hardcode picklist-values is the worst option, because you will end up in maintaining them redundatly multiple times, loose configurability by admins and significantly higher implementation efforts.

Comment: Following this question since I think this is something that hasn't been addressed in Lightning.

Comment: @akarnid This would be a massive missing piece if there is no viable workaround. What needs to be done is pretty clear (query schema, transaltions, record-types with apex and deliver the values to the controller.js), but if it's already on the roadmap at Salesforce, it would waste a lot of dev-time to implement it on our own. Maybe I have to implement it anyway, if I can't wait, but it's no fun...

Answer (score 4):

There is something...

I found this post [Lightning - How to use force:inputField?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield/96645#96645) and I'm validating this markup

```
<force:inputField value="{!v.YourAttributeNameForTheSObject.YourFieldname}" />
```

It's in the documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_inputField.htm

The description is very puristic (no further explanation, no example) and this is currently the only match in the documentation I found. It leaves many questions open.

And it works partly. As @Andrew discoverd, picklists come up disabled. Using jQuery to wipe the `disabled=""` makes them editable and I was surprisingly be able to change a picklist-value and get it saved.

So what does this tell us?

- Is this officially available or not?
- What is it capable of and what not?
- Should we use it or not?
- Will there be an improvement of documentation and functionality soon?

Please let us know, so that we can plan ahead. This is nothing small. This is very very big - at least in my opinion, since to use ui:inputXXXX is very poor compared to force:inputField